# Permission denied Php script

Tags: php, ubuntu, chmod, mkdir

The Php code creates nested directories and sets them permissions:

```
$pathToFile = 'public/loaded/' . $category . date('/Y/m/d/H/i/');
        $pathToFile = str_replace('//', '/', $pathToFile);
        if(!file_exists($pathToFile)){
            mkdir($pathToFile, 0775, true);
        }

        chmod( $pathToFile, 0775);
```

Result of this action is :

> Message: mkdir(): Permission denied Message: chmod(): No such file or
>   directory

In terminal Ubuntu i tried change permission on root directory **/public**:

> chmod -R ug+rw /public

But this command helped, so, what permission must be on folder where loads all users images and documents?

> chmod 777 -R public

Comment: post the value of `$pathToFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir()` requires a full path, not a relative one.

Try this instead:

```
$pathToFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/public/loaded/' . $category . date('/Y/m/d/H/i/');
```